# The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to create tables through code-first approach. I have two tables "CrimeReport" and "ReportDescription" and they have one to one relationship.

```
[Table("CrimeReport")]
    public class CrimeReport
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
         public  int  ImageId { get; set; }
         public virtual ReportDescription ReportDescription { get; set; }

    }


    [Table("ReportDescription")]
    public class ReportDescription
    {



        [Key]
        public int ImageId { get; set; }
        public virtual CrimeReport CrimeReport { get; set; }

    }
```

I am getting an exception when I write the command "add-migration try" inside package console.

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'codefirst.Models.ReportDescription' and 'codefirst.Models.CrimeReport'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mark `ReportDescription.CrimeReport` with the `[Required]` attribute:

```
[Table("ReportDescription")]
public class ReportDescription
{
    [Key]
    public int ImageId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual CrimeReport CrimeReport { get; set; }

}
```

Otherwise EF is unable to determine that `CrimeReport` and `ReportDescription` is a **required:required** relationship and share `ImageId` as the key.

The equivalent FluentAPI mapping would be:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ReportDescription>()
        .HasRequired(x => x.CrimeReport)
        .WithRequiredDependent(x => x.ReportDescription);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir..... I was stuck badly and you solved my problem. Can you tell me one more thing ? 

  if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                using (UsersContext db = new UsersContext())
                {

                    
                    db.LoginData.Add(new LoginData { UserId = 1, Username = "ahealalo", Password ="master"});
                    
                    db.SaveChanges();

                }




            }




            }


I m writing this code to save data in LoginData but when i check my database no values are set where is the problem ?

Comment: It could worth a separate question as it requires more details. However, did you make sure your `ModelState.IsValid` is true? Did you validate that the connection-string is indeed pointing to the right database?